# About the definition of topological constructs

Tags: category-theory

A category $\mathfrak{A}$ is said a topological construct if there is a topological functor $U: \mathfrak{A} \longrightarrow {\bf Set}$ such that $U_{ob}^{-1}(X)$ is a small set for each $X \in Obj({\bf Set})$ and constant functions lift to morphisms in $\mathfrak{A}$. Now, what does exactly mean the last condition?

I interpret it as follows: if $c: X \longrightarrow Y$ is a constant, then there exist $A,B \in Obj(\mathfrak{A})$ and arrow $f \in Hom_\mathfrak{A}(A,B)$ such that $U(A)=X$, $U(B)=Y$ and $U(f)=c$. Is my interpretation correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's slightly stronger than that!

It says that for *any* $A$ and $B$ with $UA = X$ and $UB = Y$ there is some $f : A \to B$ so that $Uf = c$.

The picture to have in mind (as indicated by the "lift" terminology) is this one:

[image: a lifting diagram]

If we ever have a constant function downstairs, we can *always* "lift it" to a function upstairs, for any choice of upstairs objects we like.

Unless the creators were out of their mind, the category of topological spaces should probably be a "topological construct", so let's use it as an instructive example.

The property you mentioned would say that for any two sets $X$ and $Y$ and for any constant function $c : X \to Y$ we can find topologies $\tau_X$ and $\tau_Y$ which make $c$ continuous.

Of course, we *know* that this is too weak. For *any* topologies on $X$ and $Y$ we want, constant functions will always be continuous. The definition reflects this power, and says that for any two structures in $\mathfrak{A}$ the constant functions are always $\mathfrak{A}$-continuous.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: +1 for "Unless the creators were out of their mind ..." - mathematics needs some lively language :D